# What is the ThreadPoolExecutor and why would my discord py program be generating so many?

Tags: python, multithreading, discord.py, profiling

In my code I only make two or three real threads to get some API data with threading. Then some tasks using discord.py's create_task.

However when I am performing bot commands and using the bot during profiling I was shocked to see how many threads were running after about 10 minutes (and it continued increasing after the screenshot below).

Why would my code be making so many ThreadPoolExecutor threads as pictured below? [image]

I have a function that reports errors to me which I call via:

```
client.loop.create_task(reportError())
```

I also have another command which executes this line:

```
asyncio.create_task(channel.send("Message the bot sends to discord"))
```

Comment: Re, "Why would my [program] be generating so many?" Nobody can answer that unless they know more about your program. What does the code look like that creates those tasks?

Comment: I edited the main post to include examples of how I am running create_task

Comment: Yes, but that's just two lines of code. Still not much to go on. I don't know `discord`, so I probably won't be able to answer the question myself, but I'm pretty sure that anybody who _can_ answer it is going to need to see more. I'm guessing that `create_task(...)` submits a task to a thread pool, but your question is not about submitting the tasks, it's about how so many pools get created.

Comment: I think I might have better luck asking how to properly use create task since I can't share much of the code, how do I close this question? Should I just delete it?

Comment: Delete works, but FYI, have a look here: http://sscce.org/ If you can pare your program down to a minimum number of lines that still show the behavior that you don't understand, but don't give away any company secrets, you might get better help from here. On the other hand, in the process of trying to prepare the SSCCE, you might discover the answer for yourself, and sharpen your debugging skills in the process.